# Selecting Child Objects Recursively in a JSON Object

Tags: c#, json.net

How is it possible to select all child objects in a JSON object? For example we have a JSON object which contains all organization units of a company and we want to select all organization units which start with the letter A.

I couldn't find any solution which selects all child objects recursively like it does in XPath's `SelectNodes` method.

```
{
  "orgname": "Org A",
  "subOrgs": [
    {
      "orgname": "Org B",
      "subOrgs": [
        {
          "orgname": "Org A",
          "subOrgs": [
            {
              "orgname": "Org B",
              "subOrgs": []
            },
            {
              "orgname": "Org C1",
              "subOrgs": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "orgname": "Org A1",
          "subOrgs": [
            {
              "orgname": "Org B2",
              "subOrgs": []
            },
            {
              "orgname": "Org C1",
              "subOrgs": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "orgname": "Org C",
      "subOrgs": [
        {
          "orgname": "Org A4",
          "subOrgs": [
            {
              "orgname": "Org B2",
              "subOrgs": []
            },
            {
              "orgname": "Org C3",
              "subOrgs": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "orgname": "Org A5",
          "subOrgs": [
            {
              "orgname": "Org B4",
              "subOrgs": []
            },
            {
              "orgname": "Org C2",
              "subOrgs": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: c#? Then try Linq. Have you tried anything? Otherwise please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: yes it's c#, and yes I tried and searched through stackoverflow, but I couldn't find anything as simple as xml's selectNodes method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [LINQ-to-JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) query like this:

```
var orgs = JObject.Parse(json);

var orgsStartingWithA = 
    orgs.DescendantsAndSelf()
        .OfType<JObject>()
        .Where(t => t["orgname"] != null && t["orgname"].Value<string>().StartsWith("Org A"))
        .ToList();

foreach (var org in orgsStartingWithA)
{
    Console.WriteLine(org["orgname"]);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mi7X6k